# Adapting LWE Trapdoors for Ring-LWE

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe, trapdoor, ring-lwe

In the paper [Trapdoors for Lattices: Simpler, Tighter, Faster, Smaller](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/501.pdf) by Micciancio and Peikert, they present the following theorem about the existence of trapdoor for LWE.

*Theorem 5.1:* There is an algorithm $\mathsf{GenTrap}(1^n,1^m,q)$ that, given any $n\geq 1, q\geq 2$ and $m=\mathcal{O}(n\log q)$, outputs a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}_q$ and a trapdoor $\mathbf{R}$ such that:

1. $\mathbf{A}$ is indistinguishable from a uniformly chosen matrix; and
2. there is an algorithm $\mathsf{Invert}$ that, given $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e}$ (with $\mathbf{s}\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}_q$, $\mathbf{e}\in\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $||\mathbf{e}||<q/\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n\log q})$) and a trapdoor $\mathbf{R}$, outputs $\mathbf{s}$ and $\mathbf{e}.$

They mention that the results in the paper can be straightforwardly adapted to the ring setting (Ring-LWE), however, they don't give details on that. What would be an equivalent result to this one in the ring setting?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of plain matrix, a matrix similar this (but bigger):

```
+a -h -g -f -e -d -c -b
+b +a -h -g -f -e -d -c
+c +b +a -h -g -f -e -d
+d +c +b +a -h -g -f -e
+e +d +c +b +a -h -g -f
+f +e +d +c +b +a -h -g
+g +f +e +d +c +b +a -h
+h +g +f +e +d +c +b +a
```

which one can deduce it's equivalant in addition and multiplication to a polynomial reduced by $X^8+1$. And here, the polynomial is the "Ring".

And instead of plain matrix of $n$ x $m$, we use a $1$ x $2$ matrix of polynomials.

Note: the arithmetical difference between matrix-represented polynomial rings and plain matrices, is that the former is commutative in multiplication, while the latter is not.

Comment: I think that the matrix $\textbf A$ should actually be replaced by a vector of independently sampled polynomials. The matrix you wrote here is actually the basis of the ideal lattice generated by the polynomial $f(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + ... + hx^7$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x] / <x^8 + 1>$.

Comment: Ok if we replace $A$ with another equivalent form for polynomial-case, then why the resulting matrix is close to uniform? I am not sure for the RLWE we can say case 1  of the above theorem is satisfied.

Comment: I think point 1 should be instead interpreted as "$A$ is indistinguishable from a uniformly chosen *polynomial*" when adapted to ring setting. @A.Soleimani

Comment: for the product of two polynomials $ a.b$ over the ring, we can represent it as a matrix multiplication $A\mathbf{b}$ where $A$ is similar to what you have written above and $\mathbf{b}$ is the vector representation of $b$. My question is that why $A$ has such structure? where can I find how $A$ is computed? I think it should be due to Chineas reminder. Do you have any reference?